# Error Trying to save Image to django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, beautifulsoup, django-file-upload

I used beautiful soup to **scrape** and extract images from a website describe below successfully but when I viewed the extracted images they appear as Url as shown below. I then experience difficulty in attempting to save the scraped image  to my django database as a particular error shown below keeps on appearing. After I got the error  I also tried using a forloop to create the post because I thought am trying to save a list element in a single data but it still shown the same or I got the same error **not commited** but when I remove the image **scrape** data from the file in title, summary, content and try to save to django database.it was a success.
Saving image is the problem and I need help

Below is my sample code

My scraped images appear as a list of url as shown below

https://people.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ad1-746x375.jpg
https://people.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/caroon-1-600x375.jpg

something like this brought the images

```
images = [i['data-src'] for i in soup.find_all('img', {'class','attachment-jnews-750x375 size-jnews-750x375 lazyload wp-post-image'})]
```

but am unable to save the images **scraped** above like this because it will bring an error

```
Post.objects.create(
                title=title,
                content_1=paragraphs,
                image=images,
                sources=lnk,
            )
```

this will bring an error when i try saving to models

```
class Post(models.Model):
               title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank = True, help_text='Maximum 160 Title characters.')
               image = models.FileField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True,  help_text='You must upload original image before continuing.')
```

```
if file and not file._committed: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

and I try using for loop but the same error exist too

```
for image in images: 
             / Post.objects.create(title=title,
                content_1=paragraphs,
                image=images,
                sources=lnk,
)
```

and I got this error also

```
if file and not file._committed: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: Seems like you are passing list of images, not one image.

Comment: @SergeyPugach please show me a way out - I need your help, yes am passing a list of images and that is why I used a forloop in my code

Comment: In the for loop, while creating a Post object, you are passing `images` to where you have to pass `image`, since images is the list you are traversing and image is the list object in current loop state. Also your code have indentation issue in the for loop

Comment: Dea @Akash please can you show me a good example sir am still confused because the image is the list object and images is the list and I used the  object to transverse the list- can you help me a little further

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap

Comment: Dear @Akash I got a name error : name 'image' is not defined. When I pass for image in images

Comment: Dear @Akash I got a name error : name 'image' is not defined. When I pass for image in images

Comment: Please check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Please change your for loop code snippet with this

```
for image in images:
    Post.objects.create(
        title=title,
        content_1=paragraphs,
        image=image,
        sources=lnk,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks much @Akash I really do appreciate

Comment: I hope it solved your problem, upvote if it did.

Comment: Dear @Akash Okay am running the code write a way- how do I upvote it sir

Comment: this images are not showing even thou i have been able to save the post succesfully this images are not appearing in my post atall but there is an image sigb alone is it because it is not uploaded or it is a link am scraping

Comment: Where are the images not appearing? In the template? Can you check in the admin panel to confirm the images are being saved?